# Middle div 100% width

Tags: css, html, width

How would i make my middle div take the remaining space left in width, but still staying in its place beside the 2 other divs?
Also if i remove either of the 2 divs on the sides, the main div should just take what space there is left?

Code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
    <div class="sidebar">1</div>
    <div class="content-box">2</div>
    <div class="sidebar">3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3Hr5/2/

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of how you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is using a table since you want all of them to be on the same row but with their own heights.
Html:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="sidebar">1</td>
        <td class="content-box">2</td>
        <td class="sidebar">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Css:

```
.sidebar {
    width:225px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.content-box {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Here is the fiddle edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/mDpEX/

//Flipbed

Comment: That might just be the solution...
Not a big fan of having to use a table inside it now.. but i guess theres not that many other options

Comment: grooo... table layouts? That's a little to 20th Century for me :) I'd do it either server-side by applying varying classes to the `div` depending on the chosen layout for the page (e.g `.onequarter`,`onehalf`,`threequarters` etc.) or deliver a fixed width site to all users and modify it using jQuery, perhaps?

Comment: Saying that table layouts is "uncool" and then suggesting a much more complicated partial solution seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Table layouts being uncool is irrelevant, they are generally semantically incorrect for most layout uses (except tabular data). This means that the browser may interpret the information incorrectly in some cases (screen-readers for instance).

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a solution, merely a potential route to investigate. Apologies if my attempt at humour appeared dismissive. A jQuery approach might be too heavy handed, but the table layout is very inflexible and semantically incorrect, if you care for such things. When I put together a bespoke template for a CMS I always use server-side calculation to determine how many columns a particular page has and apply the relevant class to each containing div column. This way you aren't trying to hack something tenuous together in CSS which may fall apart under given circumstances.

Comment: I ended up using this, not the most elegant solution... but it works, and i cant seem to get it working otherwise... unless i use JS.. and i wanna avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use table for layout, you can make use of css3 *display table, table-cell* properties,

```css
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#left, #middle, #right {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
}
#left, #right {
    width: 150px;
    background: green;
}
#middle {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69e2cbck/)

More on [css display properties](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is indeed the right answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i didn't get your question correctly. If you are looking to align your div on to the remaining space after your first div ie after **sidebar** div simply put width of **content-box** as 50%(or the size you want).

Comment: They would still fall into different rows if 50% of the page + 2*225 px > window width. Also they would not cover the full page if same size is > window width.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/U3Hr5/3/).

The HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="sidebar">1</div>
        <div class="content-box">2</div>
        <div class="sidebar">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:225px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.content-box {
    clear:left;
    background-color:red;
    width:225px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how much you want the layout to respond to resizing without using JavaScript and what browsers you're trying to cater for. If your layout is essentially static and you just want to respond to width changes then you can use something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3Hr5/4/

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="left sidebar">1</div>
        <div class="content-box">2</div>
        <div class="right sidebar">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.span12 {
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 225px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.left{left: 0;}
.right{right:0}
.content-box {
    margin-left: 225px;
    margin-right: 225px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: This wont work if one of the sidebars gets removed since the content box would still keep it's margins.

Comment: If you're removing the sidebar manually, then change the CSS to match. If you're removing the sidebar in JavaScript, simply update the margin with JavaScript too.

Comment: This solution also has trouble with adding a footer since the use of absolute positioning removes the element out of the DOM flow. A footer will sit under/over the side column if it extends beyond the central content.

Comment: Indeed. Personally, I'd be inclined to ditch the `div` elements and turn them into three `span` elements with `display: inline-block;`. But you need to know more about your widths for that, simple enough with some JavaScript involvement.

Comment: Could also use some CSS media queries to load different layouts for different browser sizes.

Comment: No reason to drop the DIVs in favour of spans... just convert their display to inline-block. The small problem with this though is limited support historically.

Comment: Yes, you'll get bad behaviour in early IE if you start with `div`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/kKGVr/

Basically, if you don't wrap the content in a containing div it will expand to fill the available space - you can test this by removing the divs called #left or #right. This will also allow you to add a footer because no absolute positioning is used.

It will fall down, however, if the central column becomes longer than the side columns... solution? Not sure, perhaps use javascript to adjust the height of the side columns so they are always at least as long as the central column.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="right">...</div>
    <div id="left">...</div>
    content here
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#left{width: 200px;background:#f00;float:left}
#right{width:200px;background:#0f0;float:right}
```